# Why does BFS gives different running time for different node positions in same graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have a line graph, which consists of 100 nodes, which are labeled from 0 to 99.

Which looks something like this:

```
0--1--2--3....98--99
```

And I use BFS, DFS, Dijkstra's algorithms to find the shortest path from node 0 to all the other nodes in first case, and I do the same for node 55(Starting node) in second case and node 99 for the third.

But in BFS, the time taken in the last case is double the time taken in the first, but in both cases the node position are graphically same. I have attached the running time in the [image].

The for and while loops in BFS are visited the same number of time, I would like to know, why is it taking different time in the three cases??

By the way, it is implemented in C++ and vector of vectors is used to store the graph.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: did you run it multiple times? Results might vary quite a lot.

Anyways, there is a good chance that it is because of caching issues. Computers usually work quite well when you access an array from 0, because they immediately cache (a part of) the array from the index you are accessing. But if you start from the end of the array, it will not have the entire array in a fast cache. (this is no different for a vector, since a vector is simply a dynamically size able array)

Also, you should not test algorithm speed this way, you can't really compare them like this. Because if you first run BFS, it has simply not yet cached the entire array. But when you have ran DFS, the entire array is probably in a fast cache for the processor. I would recommend taking a larger graph and check for both sparse and dense graphs. Also, I would make sure to write individual programs for each algorithm to check using a utility like `time`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I looked into what you told and now, the results make lot of sense.